# can I use grant_type=client_credentials for google api?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I create a clientid, and clientcredentials in google console. when I request the token with `grant_type=client_credentials`. I got `401 unauthrorized`.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized",
  "error_uri": ""
}
```

Comment: 401=The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Comment: I use Authorization=Basic <base64(cientid:clientcredentials)>

Answer (score 9):

The error means that you are not authenticated. Also client_credentials is not a valid value for grant_type that I am aware of.

The only ones I know of are

- authorization_code
- refresh_token

It looks like `grant_type=client_credentials` is part of the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) for Oauth2 but its not something I have seen implemented in Googles Authentication servers.

**Anwser**:  No to my knowledge you cant use grant_type=client_credentials with Google APis.

**update**: just got word back from Google. I was correct they do not support this grant_type.

Comment: I have a server talk to google. Then for the case do not need user grant, how to do? shoud I use this  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?

Comment: If you are working with service account authentication I recommend you find the client library for your chosen language.   Coding service accounts manually isn't easy  as you can see by the rest calls in your link.

Comment: Thanks, sure i will use the library. I just want to know the api flow first. seems the service account is the right way.

Comment: I have an article on the Oauth2 flow http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/ However the flow for building service account is just to much I have never stat down to try and create a article on that one.

Answer (score 4):

The Grant Type: Client Credentials (`client_credentials`) is not supported by Google OAuth 2.0. Google only supports two types of OAuth grants:

- authorization_code
- refresh_token

The Grant Type Client Credentials is used for obtaining an Access Token for the account specified by `Client ID` and is not used for User Authentication. This type of access is not supported by Google.

The OP was also using Basic Authorization: `base64(Client_ID:Client_Secret)` and this form is not supported by Google.

There are a few OAuth servers that support these additional forms such as IBM's App ID. Google OAuth 2.0 is not one of them.