# OAuth2 (unsupported_grant_type) Invalid grant_type: client_credentials

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch access token for Google Drive API to use it for subsequent requests from my Python script. However I am getting an invalid grant_type error which is kind of confusing.

I am using `oauthlib` and `requests_oauthlib` since `oauth2client` has officially been deprecated.

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)

token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly")
```

This is the error I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sample.py", line 10, in
>   
>       token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
>   client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,
>   scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly")   File
>   "/Users/kaybus/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py",
>
> line 244, in fetch_token
>       self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)   File
>   "/Users/kaybus/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py",
>
> line 408, in parse_request_body_response
>       self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)   File "/Users/kaybus/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py",
>
> line 379, in parse_token_response
>       validate_token_parameters(params)   File "/Users/kaybus/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py",
>
> line 386, in validate_token_parameters
>       raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)   File "/Users/kaybus/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/errors.py",
>
> line 406, in raise_from_error
>       raise cls(**kwargs) oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.UnsupportedGrantTypeError:
>   (unsupported_grant_type) Invalid grant_type: client_credentials

I am sure many might have bumped into this problem. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Please let me know how you solved it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like Google APIs do not support `client_credentials` grant_type from what I saw in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102110/can-i-use-grant-type-client-credentials-for-google-api.

Comment: In addition to that, you are getting those errors because you might be adding the url data (username, password, grant_type) to the header and not to the body element. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31985839/5832311). You may also refer with this [thread](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/issues/424).