# Make Flask Return Credentials for Google Auth in JSON format

Tags: python, json, flask, google-api, google-api-python-client

I've been grappling with an issue for weeks while trying to run an app that utilizes Google APIs with OAuth in Python through a headless linux server. I've tried to do this the easy way using Oauth packages but Google's APIs don't accept commonly passed arguments by these functions. That issue is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201485/accomplishing-oauth2-0-authorization-with-refresh-token-through-python-google-a/67207000#67207000).

I've instead tried to follow an example on [Google's documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_5) which makes use of Flask to create and return the credentials. I've attempted to make my own webpage that will simply return the credentials in JSON format:

```
@app.route('/credentials')
def get_credentials():
    if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect('authorize')
    #oauth_refresh = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token) 
    # Load credentials from the session.
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        **flask.session['credentials'])
    creds_dict = {'token': credentials.token,
          'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
          'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
          'client_id': credentials.client_id,
          'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
          'scopes': credentials.scopes}
    creds_dict = jsonify(creds_dict)
    return creds_dict
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification.
  # ACTION ITEM for developers:
  #     When running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'

  # Specify a hostname and port that are set as a valid redirect URI
  # for your API project in the Google API Console.
  app.run('localhost', 8080, debug=True)
```

And then I try to use requests to simply grab the result of this data so I can proceed with creating the Google service:

```
res = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/credentials")
cred = res.json()
service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
```

However, the .json() line always results in

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Because this is returning text/html not JSON, despite me explicitly making the flask function return JSON. I've tried multiple solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view) to no avail. You can take a look at the random HTML generated instead [here](https://pastebin.com/2wdeB9d3).

Comment: Can you confirm it's not hitting the authorize redirect? Sidenote, as of flask 1.1.0, you can just return the dict from the response and jsonify will automatically be called.

Comment: Yes I can confirm, returning the dict alone results in exactly the same thing. So does using json.dumps().