# Fail to get Access token from Google

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, backend, access-token

I want to get in-app product list, so need to "Access token" when it requests.
But return code is 400, invalid grant_type="password"

id, password, and oauth2.Config is setting.

- go library version
  golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20200107190931-bf48bf16ab8d

#### code

- auth2.go

```
// PasswordCredentialsToken converts a resource owner username and password
// pair into a token.
//
// Per the RFC, this grant type should only be used "when there is a high
// degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client
// is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application),
// and when other authorization grant types are not available."
// See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3 for more info.
//
// The provided context optionally controls which HTTP client is used. See the HTTPClient variable.
func (c *Config) PasswordCredentialsToken(ctx context.Context, username, password string) (*Token, error) {
    v := url.Values{
        "grant_type": {"password"},
        "username":   {username},
        "password":   {password},
    }
    if len(c.Scopes) > 0 {
        v.Set("scope", strings.Join(c.Scopes, " "))
    }
    return retrieveToken(ctx, c, v)
}
```

- back-end

```
clientID := os.Getenv("CLIENT_ID")
clientSecretKey := os.Getenv("CLIENT_SECRET_KEY")
id := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_ID")
password := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_PASSWORD")

OAuthConf = &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     clientID,
    ClientSecret: clientSecretKey,
    Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
}

// get token
token, err := OAuthConf.PasswordCredentialsToken(context.Background(), id, password)
if err != nil {
    log.Err.Printf("PasswordCredentialsToken : [%s]\n", err)
    c.Abort()
    return
}
log.Info.Printf("token : [%+v]\n", token)
```

#### response

```
oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: password"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that that type of grant is supported by Google in Oauth 2.0? from this answer it seems that it's not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102110/can-i-use-grant-type-client-credentials-for-google-api

Comment: Google OAuth does not support the password grant type. Which identity provider are you trying to use? If you are trying to use Google, then the user must authenticate in the browser. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: @JohnHanley I love your answer, maybe please correct link url about the sentence "not support the password grant type"??, because it goes to main page in OAuth2.

Comment: My link is for the main page of OAuth. The left side has an index so that you can select the type of authorization.